# csf firewall deny

Tags: csf

How can I pass a comment to the command  csf -d

so I do not have to edit csf.deny, find the line and add a comment as to why it was manually denied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this http://configserver.com/free/csf/readme.txt

You can just do it!

```
You can also include comments when using the csf -a or csf -d commands, but in
those cases you must not use a # like this:

csf -d 11.22.33.44 Added because I don't like them
```